# RESTful API - Once-writeable resource

Tags: rest, http

What is the idiomatic way to represent a once-writeable resource in a RESTful API (in HTTP)? In CRUD terms it should be possible to create the resource but to disallow updates?

EDIT:

Just to add the clarification in the comment on Rosenheimer's answer below. I'd like to allow the client to specify the URL rather than have it generated by a `POST` handler.

Comment: what kind of convention will you be using? PUT ./resources/{id} for creation?

Comment: I think I'd prefer a `PUT` to a `POST` as it feels semantically better. But I suspect that the "write-once" semantic isn't idempotent.

Comment: Yes you are right. There is no obvious respond to your question. You can always reply using a 4xx response status. But from a client perspective it is not easy. So I suggest that you make a distinction using POST only for creation and forbid the PUT/PATCH.

Answer (score 0):

If the resource doesn't exist before (that means "once-writable" actually is "creation" of the resource) then it would be easy to just call the parent for a `POST`, like this: `POST example.com/Resources` to send the resource.
Later, do not allow either `PUT` or `PATCH` to the specific resource at `example.com/Resources/123` where `123` would be the identifier of the resource.

So the resource can be written once but can not be changed later.

Comment: Agree "once-writeable" is actually "creation".

But I want the client to be able specify the URL - i.e. is there a way for the client to say "create the resource at this specific URL or fail if that URL is already taken"?

It wouldn't be difficult to specify the URL within the body of the POST but I was wondering if it was possible to represent this purely in HTTP.

Comment: Sure, you can either, as you already said, include the identifier of the resource in the resource itself (as a property of the object in the body) or just include it as an URL parameter like this: POST example.com/Resources?ID=123; this could then either respond with a 201 - Created or 423 - Locked

Answer (score 0):

You could use the HTTP status `405 Method Not Allowed` or `403 Forbidden` to forbid subsequent update.

Some use [`POST`](http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/methods.html) for resource creation:

```
# C of CRUD
POST ./phones -> 200 OK with the id of the object created
# R or CRUD
GET ./phones/{id}
# U of CRUD
PATCH/PUT ./phones/{id}
# D of CRUD
DELETE ./phones/{id}
```

Some may use `PUT` for object creation but the issue of using `PUT` is that the method have 2 meaning for the client.

Comment: `PUT` has the semantics of replacing the entity referenced by the invoked URI with the payload found within the request - nothing more, nothing less. If the entity is not yet available only than `PUT` has a similar semantics as `POST` though it still "replaces" the current content with the one found within the request.

Comment: @RomanVottner Yes there is still 2 different things that is happening when using PUT to create an resource and replace a resource. It give a lot of trouble to have both semantic in the same method. The behavior from a client perspective is less clear.

Comment: NO! The semantics is just replace what should be/is there with what is contained within the request. If there is an update or a creation is not relevant for `PUT`. The effect is what matters. At the end of the request the resource represented by the invoked URI has to have the content of the request body.

Comment: You care about the semantic of the PUT. I care about the semantic for the client. Using PUT for object creation is ok but there would be no obvious way to respond the OP questions.

Comment: Furthermore if you are going to build a high availability API is going to be difficult if you use PUT for creating object and replacing the content. Practically speaking one is going to be fast the other might take a while and you end up in an unpredictable result. SLA definition is not so easy in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct would be to accept `PUT` method for the first time resource is saved and return 409 Conflict HTTP status code on any subsequent attempt to update already existing resource.

Comment: This isn't idempotent though which `PUT` is supposed to be.

Comment: I take it back. Idempotence seemingly doesn't extend to the response code. But I think it would be better to return, say, a 204 rather than a failure in the case that the PUT body matches the current content.